# how to examine onKeyPress event in console

Tags: javascript

I have the following line:

```
onKeyPress={(e)=>(e.key==='Enter' ? this.addTodo(e):null)}
```

assume in the addToo() we have console.log(e)

where can you examine things like:

```
e.target
e.key
```

in the console I'm getting the following:

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, 
isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}

[[Handler]]:Object
[[Target]]:SyntheticKeyboardEvent
[[IsRevoked]]:false
```

I can expand these but can't locate e.key or e.target

UPDATE: adding e.persist() before the console.log preserves the information and then you can examine the details of e in the console.log

Comment: I'm very confused - why does not adding `console.log(e.key)` to the `addTodo()` method work for you? Or even just `e` which in at least Chrome will dump the whole event with all of that data.

Comment: @DCR What are *you* getting in the console...? Are you asking how to actually *look* at the console? F12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to add e.persist() and then you can examine the contents of e in the console